# How to tie a backend to Watson's Conversation service?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using Conversation service in my application, at the backend I want to use the corpus I have setup so that I can ask deep technical questions since my corpus has been populated with Technical videos and articles spanning 20+ years.

Can you please point me to examples where Conversation service has been integrated with backend Watson services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of integrating Retrieve and Rank at 
http://conversation-enhanced.mybluemix.net/

The code to show this integration is housed at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-enhanced

Comment: Thanks, Dan!. I looked at the Demo and the code in GitHub. I don't see how Dialog API in Conversation is pulling answers from a corpus. Can you please paste that code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I did find the code where the query is constructed with the user's input and the backend corpus is searched , the class in github is here : https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-enhanced/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/apis/conversation_enhanced/rest/ProxyResource.java